# Calling normal method in Asp.net MVC to insert record without ActionResult redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-partialview, asp.net-apicontroller

Here is my scenario. I have a main view with a datatable. That datatable has a child record that contains a partial view that is loaded when clicked. That partial view has its own button created to insert a record into the database using @URL.Action() that calls the current Action Result. My issue is that I don't need to reload the page or really have the page do anything. When I click the button I just want a simple method to fire (doesn't need to return any action result) so I can run my code to check for existing records in the database, if not create a new one and insert it. Everything I have tried either redirects the page, reloads it or creates an blank page return. I feel like I am missing some simple. I just want to call a typical method by clicking the button from the partial view that has the form data. Can someone tell me what I am missing or have I just been staring at it too long.

Comment: You need to use ajax if you want to stay on the same page (and your method should at least return a `JsonResult` indicating success or otherwise)

Comment: I tried an ajax.beginform action with a json result. It still took me away from where I was and returned just a page full of json when the button was clicked. It didn't keep me on the same page.

Comment: I have resolved. The ajax request worked after I included jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js and passed the model to the json return instead of creating a new json object.